# Preadjoint of unbounded operators on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces. Let $T : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ be a unbounded linear map where $X^*$ represents the Banach dual of $X$.

My question is, there exists a dense domain $D \subseteq X$ and a linear map $S : D \rightarrow Y$ such that
$$
\langle Sx , y \rangle = \langle x, Ty \rangle 
$$
for any $x \in D$, $y \in Y^*$? (Please, read the bra-ket notation as a duality product). Are $S$ or $D$ unique?

**Motivation**: I want to prove that a map $T : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ is $w^*$-continuous, and I know a `candidate' $S:X \rightarrow Y$ for being the preadjoint is bounded on norm. The only doubt that remains for me is if there exists an unbounded preadjoint for $T$, because if not, I am afraid I am doing void reasonings...

Thank you

Comment: $D$ is certainly not unique because you can replace $D$ with any dense subset of itself and the claim will still hold.

Comment: Also your claimed equation doesn't make sense for all $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ as you wrote, but only for $x \in D$, $y \in D(T)$.

Comment: First of all, thank for your answer. I have corrected the errors that you pointed out. In my case, the map is well-defined on all $Y^*$. In that case, the (possibly unbounded) preadjoint exist? Under which conditions $D=X$ and $S$ is bounded? Thank you for your patience